# Not able to login in neo4j browser from other machine

Tags: neo4j

I have Neo4j CE 3.2.1 running on machine1 (Windows 7). I am able to access it locally (machine-1) from Google Chrome browser. I want access it from other machine-2 running Ubuntu and Firefox. So I have added following properties apart from the default properties:

```
dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7687
dbms.connector.http.address=0.0.0.0:7474
```

My friend is able to access it from his machine (machine-3 running Windows+Chrome). But I am not able to access it from machine-2. It gives following error:

> N/A: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

While login I am entering same login credential on all three machines:

> Host: bolt://machine-1-ip:7687
>   Username: neo4j
>   Password: password

Then why I am not able to access this instance of neo4j running on machine-1 from machine-2?

[image]

Comment: Can you check nmap -p 7687 machine-1 from machine-2 ? Is the port open ?

Comment: Yeah it said `Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn`. But dont know what does that mean... `-Pn` ?

Comment: But I am able to open neo4j browser on machine-2. Its just that am not able login.

Comment: -Pn is used to avoid using the ping port (which may be firewalled so try that option). Yes, I understand the browser is working, just trying to determine what may be wrong.

Comment: can there be any security certificate related issue? (Am accessing browser over `http`). Also I am able to access neo4j running on machine-3 from machine-1, but not from machine-2. Same. Able to access browser, but giving same error while login.

Comment: That's also a possibility. Do you have another browser available on machine-2 (Chrome instead of Firefox for example) ?

Comment: downloading...low speed....also the machine is behind freakin proxy...so downloading it on windows laptop with mobile network...will copy chrome deb using winscp

Comment: Still try the nmap -Pn -p 7678 machine-1 too please ... both machines are obviously in a restricted environment, so making sure on the ports is a good thing to do.

Comment: ok wait for 5 minutes, machine-1 is a windows laptop which I have now connected to 4g hotspot to download chrome deb, having low speed (machine-2 is ubuntu workstation)

Comment: ok ran the `nmap -Pn p` command and got [this](http://ideone.com/jKRAGy).

Comment: filtered ... so there is some sort of firewall in between ...

Comment: but then how browser is opening on 7474? is this setting on neo4j? or Is this in Windows machine-1 firewall? I really dont have privileges to change machine-1 firewall. Will changing port do?

Comment: You can check the same for port (http) 7474 and (https) 7473. I guess it will show open instead of filtered. Yes, it's very likely you are being blocked by the Windows firewall.

Comment: ok sorry, I ran `nmap` against old IP. My new IP changed since I disconnected from 4g hotspot and reconnected to the original network. It seems that only https is blocked. Here is the [output](http://ideone.com/wiWLkt).

Comment: Well, that's that excluded as a cause :-). Can you try clearing your browser cache and/or try if a private window has the same issue ?

Comment: didnt get what do you mean by "Well, that's that excluded as a cause...", no its not opening from private firefox window. And I am not able to get chrome installed on this machine. Got chrome deb. But then it required other debs. To much of effort to get all dependency debs. Sorry for super late reply.

Comment: If the bolt port (7687) and http port (7474) show "OPEN", it's not a firewall issue (that's what I meant). If you're using http the certificate should not matter. Is your FireFox up to date ? Can you use FireBug to see where it actually goes wrong ?

Comment: Can you also try the connection with bolt://<actual ip machine 1>:7687 instead of with the DNS name of the machine ?

Comment: these machines are in the same network, I was indeed trying to connect with actual IP. Never tried with dns name. Should I try with dns name? I never did that...And by the way whats that name? Machine name?

Comment: If IP is not working, DNS will not either, so don't bother with that. Can you check what FireBug says when the request fails ?

Comment: weird...was able to get chrome installed on ununtu machine today. Then tried on firefox again. Did not worked. Tried on chrome. Did not worked. Checked chrome F12 tools. It was showing `WebSocket opening handshake timed out` as can be seen in the image added to the original question. But then I tried again in firefox, it worked...   :'\